# Playing music in python

Tags: python, audio-player

```
import sys
import winsound  

songchoice=input("What song do you want to play?")

from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
root.title("Music Player")

def buttonON():
    labelImg.pack()

def buttonQuit():
    root.destroy

def buttonON():
    winsound.PlaySound("wreckingball.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)

if songchoice== "1":
    buttonON = Button(root, text="PLAY", width=5, height=2, command=buttonON)
    buttonON.pack(side=LEFT)
    buttonQUIT= Button(root, text="QUIT", width=5, height=2, command=buttonQuit)
    buttonQUIT.pack (side=LEFT)

    img=PhotoImage(file='guy.gif')
    labelImg=Label(image=img)
    labelImg.image=img
    labelImg.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure why my coding isn't working. I'm trying to play this song but when I do play it does not work. I've been working on this fore a while and it hasn't worked yet.

I am a fairly new to programming so I don't know much about this.

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Do you know that the value of `songchoice` is `"1"`? (Does `guy.gif` show up?)

Comment: It turned out that the website that I converted the song from an mp3 to a wav was dodgy. I converted using a more reliable website and it worked just fine... That made me feel pretty stupid,  thanks for the help though.